# decode html tags along with image in summernote

Tags: php, summernote

I am using the popular summernote editor to collect user import, sometimes the user include image and my script will run into a problem, the image not display whenever the user include image and other html features but if he add only image it will show. only text and html also works but combining image text and html the image is broken..

```
//this is how i collect the data before inserting to db
public function HTMLEncoder($string) {// summernote control
    $string = htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($string));
    return $string;
}
// this is how i retrieve the data from db
public function HTMLDencoder($string) {// summernote control
    $string = html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($string));
    return $string;
}

// this is how my data is stored in db 
   &lt;p&gt;gg we are working&amp;nbsp;&lt;img src=&quot;data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4SEtRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAGABoBBQABAAAAVgAAABs    BBQABAAAAXgAAAC...........
```

So here it means a p tag is at the top before the image was added in summernote